# How to print out files using if not condition in bash

Tags: bash, shell, if-statement

Say I have three files in a directory `dir`

```
touch a.ym b.ym a.job
```

And I need to print all `*.ym` if it has no corresponding `*.job` file.
So this what I tried,

```
for file in $(find ${dir} -name \*.ym);do
    filebase=$(basename $file)
    sample_id=$(echo "${filebase}"| awk -F'[.]' '{print $1}')
    if  [[ $sample_id != *".job" ]]; then
          echo "${file}"
    fi
done
```

However, the above solution is printing out both

`a.ym b.ym` files, where I need only `b.ym` file to be printed out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Bash:

To ensure that an executable script is run using the `bash` interpreter, it is important to ensure that the first characters in the script are `#!`, followed by a command that will invoke `bash`.  An example first line is:

```
#!/bin/bash
```

Usually the expansion of a glob pattern that doesn't match anything will result in the original globbing pattern.  This is not desired in our case.  In order to make a non-matching glob evaluate to an empty list of files requires the `nullglob` option to be enabled as follows:

```
shopt -s nullglob
```

The following expression evaluates to the list of files whose name ends in `.ym`, within the directory, `$dir`:

```
"$dir"/*.ym
```

The following evaluates to the filename prefix of the file, `$file`:

```
"${file%.*}"
```

And a condition that checks if a file does not exist is:

```
if [[ ! -f "${file}" ]]; then
  ... the file does not exist ...
fi
```

Combining these points results in the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s nullglob

for file in "$dir"/*.ym; do
  if [[ ! -f "${file%.*}.job" ]]; then
    echo "$file"
  fi
done
```

Answer (score 5):

I applaud your resourcefulness in using the tools you're familiar with, but you're doing a lot with the `find` and `awk` commands that can be done easier with just pure `bash`.

Try this:

### Answer

```sh
for ym_file in "${dir}"/*.ym; do
    job_file="${ym_file/.ym/.job}"
    if [[ ! -f "$job_file" ]]; then
        echo "${ym_file} has no matching job file"
    fi
done
```

### Explanation

- `"${dir}"/*.ym`: You can use a glob match in bash directly. This will error if you don't have any `.ym` files, but it won't do anything bad in this situation.
- `"${ym_file/.ym/.job}"`: This is a `bash` pattern substitution. It replaces all instances of `.ym` with `.job`. I assume those patterns won't appear in your file name except at the end.
- `[[ ! -f "$job_file" ]]`: The `-f` flag tests for the presence of a regular file, and the `!` negates it (so testing for the absence of a regular file).

Answer (score 4):

c.f. [Bash Parameter Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) and [Conditional Expressions](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Conditional-Constructs.html#Conditional-Constructs) for built-in tools.

```
for f in *.ym
do [[ -e "${f%.ym}.job" ]] || echo "$f"
done
```